# How to find approximation of variance of $i^\text{th}$ order statistic

Tags: statistics, variance, order-statistics

Given PDF and CDF of a distribution, how does one find an approximation of $(\operatorname{Var}(X_i))$ using a normal approximation of $(X_i)$?

According to "Mathematica Laboratories for Mathematical Statistics" by Jenny Baglivo (Theorem 9.1 on page 120), it is said that:

$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) \approx p(1-p) / (n+2)f(x)^2$ where $f$ is PDF, $x$ is $p^\text{th}$ quantile of the $X$ distribution, and $p = i/(n+1)$

I have $0$ ideas on how we get to this result. I am absolutely drawing at a blank. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You could think along the following lines: A Beta distribution has variance $\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2  (\alpha+\beta+1)}$.  So the $i$th order statistic of a uniform distribution has this variance with $\alpha=i, \beta=n+1-i$, which is $\frac{p(1-p)}{n+2}$.  But in general the density of the underlying distribution is not $1$ but closer to $f(x)$, so you need to scale by this (squaring as you are calculating a variance) and thus $\frac{p(1-p)}{(n+2)\,f(x)^2}$

Comment: @Henry what if we are not referring to a Beta distribution? Will the result change?

Comment: I like to think of the variance of the beta distribution as $\displaystyle \frac{\left( \frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta} \right) \left( \frac\beta{\alpha+\beta} \right)}{\alpha+\beta+1}. $

Comment: Maybe later I'll say something about this if no one else says it first......

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not sure why this is used in terms of the Beta distribution only. What if I want to find the ith statistic for, say, the Weibull distribution?

Comment: @MichaelHardy and here $p=\frac{i}{n+1}=\frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}$, $1-p=\frac{n+1-i}{n+1}=\frac\beta{\alpha+\beta}$, and  $n+2=\alpha+\beta+1$

Comment: @iphonex - the Beta distribution is to deal with the order statistic and leads to the $\frac{p(1-p)}{n+2}$ part of the expression.  It is using an underlying distribution other than a uniform distribution which introduces the $\frac1{f(x)^2}$ part of the expression

Comment: @Henry ok I understand now. Thank you very much for your help!